# Scrolling two listboxes of different lengths with one scrollbar

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar

I am facing a small problem in synchronizing my Tkinter scrollbar with two listboxes widgets. When content in two listboxes are not same I face this error otherwise, if length is same then there is no problem. Below is my short code:

```
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient='vertical')
        self.lb1 = tk.Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.lb2 = tk.Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.lb1.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.lb2.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

    def yview(self, *args):
        """connect the yview action together"""
        self.lb1.yview(*args)
        self.lb2.yview(*args)


root = tk.Tk()
# use width x height + x_offset + y_offset (no spaces!)
root.geometry("320x180+130+180")
root.title("connect 2 listboxes to one scrollbar")

app = App(root)

# load the list boxes for the test
for n in range(64+26, 64, -1): #listbox 1
    app.lb1.insert(0, chr(n)+'ell')

for n in range(70+30, 64, -1):    
    app.lb2.insert(0, chr(n)+'ell') #listbox 2

root.mainloop()
```

**What I want**

I know the error is obvious since both lists have unmatched lengths. What I want is on running above code the scrollbar should follow right synchronizing from first word i.e. `Aell` to last word which is `Zell` by order given in both lists.

The approach in my mind is to always scroll both lists with respect to length of shortest list (left side one in my case) so that I can at least match all possible points.

Lastly, I am only facing this error when I am dragging slider up and down for scrolling. But when I am simply momentarily pressing and releasing the up and down arrows on scrollbar then everything works fine.

**What I tried**

Apart from reading online, I also tried introducing events and bindings in following manner hoping to restrict the scrolling step wise, but no change.

```
self.lb1.bind('<Up>', lambda event: self.scroll_listboxes(-1))
self.lb2.bind('<Up>', lambda event: self.scroll_listboxes(-1))
self.lb1.bind('<Down>', lambda event: self.scroll_listboxes(1))
self.lb2.bind('<Down>', lambda event: self.scroll_listboxes(1))

def scroll_listboxes(self, yFactor):
#function runs when a listbox has focus and the Up or Down arrow 
#keys are pressed
    self.listbox1.yview_scroll(yFactor, "units")
    self.listbox2.yview_scroll(yFactor, "units")
```

**P.S.**

I just thought upon something, but really not sure if that's all the way correct. Since the lengths are unmatched, scrolling action varies for both list boxes. So is it possible to somehow force the scrolling action of shortest list on another list? This way another list with more contents wont be able to move freely and will have to follow scrolling pattern just as shortest content list box.

Comment: Why not simply ensure that both lists are always the same length, eg by adding some blank lines to the shorter list?

Comment: @PM2Ring I thought of that idea while i was editing code but then came to a conclusion that its not that efficient method. Even now if by somehow I am able to step wise perform scrolling while dragging slider. This problem can be solved. But maybe it requires more than what I just think.

Comment: if you want to syncrhonize on the shortest list, what do you do when the longest list goes beyond the edge of the screen? Do you just make it impossible to see that part of the list?

Comment: In that case the shortest list should get stuck at the last point and on further scrolling only points of longest list should be scrolled and visible. But as far as we have shortest list point getting successfully scrolled, the algorithm should scroll with respect to it.

Comment: I will try to vaguely express what I think. Lets say our vertical slider moves on Y axis so if Y = 5 (i.e. scrollbar moves 5 points down) due to unmatched order short list will move lets say 3 points and long one since it has more points to cover, will move 5 points. So in that scenario I want that if we move slider to any position it should cover same points on long list as covered in short list. It should impose this change on long list as well, no matter how long it is. And as you asked if its beyond screen then short list should get stuck at last point and long list should continue scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is going to be to simply add enough blank lines in the shorter list so that it has exactly the same number of elements as the longer list.

You mention in a comment that you think that would be inefficient, but I don't think that's the case unless you have tens of thousands more items in one list than in the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answers Bryan and PM2Ring. For now I too have started to think that this is the only way.