# python GUI tkinter scrollbar not working for canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am learning python GUI with Tkinter. i just created two listbox and populated those in a canvas so that i can configure canvas with scrollbar and those two listbox scroll togather when i scroll canvas. but something is not working.

Here is the structure:

```
canvas = Canvas(master)
scrollBar = Scrollbar(master)
movieListBox = Listbox(canvas) 
statusListBox = Listbox(canvas)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand = scrollBar.set)
movieListBox.config(width = 55)
statusListBox.config(width = 8)
movieListBox.pack(fill = "y", side = "left")
statusListBox.pack(fill = "y", side = "right")
canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = "y", expand = "true")
scrollBar.config(command = canvas.yview)
scrollBar.pack(fill = "y", side = "left")

for i in range(500):
    movieListBox.insert(i, "movie name")
    statusListBox.insert(i, "downloading")

master.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: there are better ways to scroll two listboxes than to put them in a canvas. Are you interested in solving the "how do I scroll two listboxes" problem, or the "how to make a scrollbar work with a canvas" problem.

Comment: A canvas only scrolls its content (added via methods such as `create_window()`), NOT its child widgets.

Comment: i am interested in learning python so i want to solve both problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to tkinter and python myself, but I did find something that works. This is from another question, (I didn't write the code) which was about having two listboxes of different lengths linked to the same scrollbar. If you copy their code (below) you'll see that it works fine for listboxes of equal length. Your question is pretty old, but I hope it helps someone. Cheers.

Where I found this:

[Scrolling two listboxes of different lengths with one scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715745/scrolling-two-listboxes-of-different-lengths-with-one-scrollbar)

```
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient='vertical')
        self.lb1 = tk.Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.lb2 = tk.Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.lb1.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.lb2.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

    def yview(self, *args):
        """connect the yview action together"""
        self.lb1.yview(*args)
        self.lb2.yview(*args)


root = tk.Tk()
# use width x height + x_offset + y_offset (no spaces!)
root.geometry("320x180+130+180")
root.title("connect 2 listboxes to one scrollbar")

app = App(root)

# load the list boxes for the test
for n in range(64+26, 64, -1): #listbox 1
    app.lb1.insert(0, chr(n)+'ell')

for n in range(70+30, 64, -1):    
    app.lb2.insert(0, chr(n)+'ell') #listbox 2

root.mainloop()
```